# Mapping all request params into an object in Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

So, url requested looks like

```
localhost:8080/contacts?id=22&name=John&eventId=11
```

and also I got an object to map request into

```
public class ContactDTO {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Long eventId;
}
```

I use a controller method like passing my request params into an object

```
@GetMapping("/contacts")
public ContactDTO contacts(ContactDTO contact) {
    // everything is awesome! contact maps clearly
    return contact;
}
```

The question is how to map like this but have different name

```
    localhost:8080/contacts?id=22&name=John&event_id=11
```

Setting @JsonAttribute doesn't works because Jackson mapper works only in requestbody. 
Maybe I should write custom HandlerMethodArgumentResolver or something like that?

P.S.
I've got a dirty hack (objectMapper is injected, so I can use @JsonAttributes),
But this case fails on array mapping, same mapping with requestbody works fine

```
@GetMapping("/contacts")
public ContactsDTO contacts(@RequestParam Map<String,String> params) {
    ContactDTO contactDTO = objectMapper.convertValue(params,ContactDTO.class);
    return contactDTO;
}
```

Comment: change mapping to `Post` and create a `QueryDto (for example)` and use it the way you want. IMHO using json is way better and will save your life.

Comment: Are you creating Rest API?

Comment: @emotionlessbananas I know how to do this in POST easily, but now I must do it in GET

Comment: @Satheeshkumar No

Comment: @AritraPaul No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is an API design requirement, it should be clearly reflected in the corresponding DTO's and endpoints.

Usually, this kind of requirement stems from a [parallel change](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ParallelChange.html) and implies that the old type queries will be disabled during the *contract* phase.

You could approach the requirement by adding the required mapping "query-parameter-name-to-property-name" by adding it to the `ContactDTO`. The simplest way would be just to add an additional setter like below

```java
public class ContactDTO {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Long eventId;

    public void setEvent_id(Long eventId) {
        this.eventId = eventId;
    }
}
```

If you prefer immutable DTO's, then providing a proper constructor should work as well

```java
@Value
public class ContactDTO {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Long eventId;

    public ContactDTO(Long id, String name, String eventId, String event_id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.eventId = eventId != null ? eventId : event_id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use something like

```
@RequestParam(name="event_id", required = true) long eventId
```

in the parameter list to change the parameter name.

Comment: I know how to change parameter name in the list of params, but I got no list of params! My method consumes automatically mapped DTO, check the question again, please

Answer (score -6):

Use @RequestBody insteaf of @requestparam.

Comment: It is GET method, and all request prams send in query url